# Deserialize large JSON in SharePoint 2010

Tags: json, parsing, sharepoint, serialization, sharepoint-2010

Json file in about 5000 entries. I use the method `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>`(string), but I get the following error:

```
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.ThrowIfMaxJsonDeserializerMembersExceeded(Int32 count)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
   at xxx.Internet.Core.Services.xxxService.DeserializeAtms(String xxxJson, List`1& xxxList)
   at xxx.Internet.Jobs.xxxFetcherJob.xxxFetcherJob.Execute(Guid contentDbId)
```

I tried to write in the web.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

but it did't help...

Comment: Have you checked the value of `AppSettings.MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` at runtime to verify that your setting is being used? SharePoint has multiple web.config files and it can be tricky to get it in the right place.

Comment: I have checked the value like this:

`System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", "SharePoint - 80").AppSettings.Settings`

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint timer jobs run under the OWSTIMER.exe process.
This process has a configuration file associated with it. We can use this config file to specify the configuration settings that are to be used in custom timer jobs.

Open the OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG and add the  tag to it.
Then add your key value pairs under this appSettings tag.

For this you have to add a reference to System.Configuration
Then you can use the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] to retrieve the values for a key from the config file.

Example: string dept = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Department"];

Original:

http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.ru/2011/03/config-file-for-sharepoint-custom-timer.html?showComment=1358842033678#c8928587895049662169